# virtualenv - which python version

Tags: python, virtualenv

If I created a virtual environment using `python3 -m virtualenv [name]` does this simply use the global version of python? If say, in 10 years time when we might all be using python 4 will running my code in the virtual environment I created today try to run the code in python4?

I read somewhere on stackoverflow that you can specify a version of python like this... `virtualenv --python="/usr/bin/python2.6" "/path/to/new/virtualenv/"`.

Will this second method make it so not matter when I try to run the code the virtual environment will have everything needed to make it run without errors?

I'm new to coding though I did play about with Visual C++ 2010 when it was current. I couldn't get any of that code to run when I tried it recently and I don't want the same to happen again!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtualenv` is a tool for creating isolated python environments, if you need to create a virtualenv with specific version of python, you can run the following command.

```bash
virtualenv myvenv -p3.10
```

This will check your system for any `python3.10` installations, and if found, it will successfully create a virtual environment, else:

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='3.10'
```

which implies that you need to have the specific version installed in your system.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

I think the first method I mentioned does do what I wanted after all but with slightly less control.

I couldn't get the -p3.6 flag to work though... I had to type longhand --python="/usr/bin/python3.6", but I always do that anyway!

Thank you